# Empty thumbnail when sharing a link on Facebook

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting an empty thumbnail when sharing a link on Facebook.

Initially, I set an `og:image` meta and it correctly worked, now I resized the image to make it appear as a big thumbnail (with image size greater than 600px on the wide side) and I don't see my thumbnail anymore.

I tried to debug the link on the Open Graph Debugger, but I still get an empty thumbnail! Does anyone have any hint on how I can fix this?

If you need it, here's the [link](http://messages-svil.ciacola.it/00002/00002/8619/shared/index.html) to the webpage, and here's how I set my meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://messages-svil.ciacola.it/00002/00002/8619/shared/preview_8619_social.png">
```

(As you can see the image exists, but Facebook doesn't show it on the post)

Thank you!

Comment: Seems to work fine for me …?

Comment: Really? It looks it like this for me: [Image](https://imgur.com/54sm2Wl)

Comment: Using mobile data it correctly loads the image while with WiFi image didn't load. What a weird thing!

Comment: That seems to be some preview mode only though?

Comment: Yes it was through Open Graph Debug tool.